# service now giving empty referrer in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, servicenow, referrer, new-window

trying to see referrer for IE11 by simple code ,but not working **with ServiceNow**. this code working in chrome but giving empty referrer in IE. here is the code ,please suggest me.

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>First Web Application</title>
</head>

<body>
    <span style="color: #ff0000; ">${errorMessage}</span>
    <form method="post">
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <a title="Link that opens in a new window"  referrerpolicy="origin" href="https://localhost:8082/welcome-get?token=st566565 "    target="_blank">Next</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IE is poor, doesn't support many features

Comment: Any solution for this issue would be appreciated...

Comment: I test the code you provide in IE and Chrome and the results are the same. I think your code snippet can't reproduce the issue. But for the cause of the issue you have, I think that's due to [IE doesn't support `referrerpolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Browser_compatibility). You can't use this policy in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The  `referrer-policy` tag means

> The " same-origin " policy specifies that a full URL, stripped for use
> as a referrer, is sent as referrer information when making same-origin
> requests from a particular client. Cross-origin requests, on the other
> hand, will contain no referrer information.

Servicenow has its own classes `"rel = noopener noreferrer nofollow` to avoid tabNabbing

```
<a title="Link that opens in a new window"  rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="https://localhost:8082/welcome-get?token=st566565 "    target="_blank">Next</a>
```

Please find the screenshot below for more information.

[image]